# count words from three texts

Tags: python, count

I must count the number of words in three texts.

```py
text1 = "He is tall, fat and ugly."

text2 = "He is a very fearful and crying boy, but intelligent."

text3 = "She has a pretty face, but she's not very smart."
```

I must use something like this:

```
def count_words(text):

    num_words = 0
```

---I must write the code here---

```
    return num_words
```

to then apply this:

```
    num_words = count_words(text1)
    print("Text 1")
    print("The word number is %d" % num_words)


    num_words = count_words(text2)
    print("Text 2")
    print("The word number is %d" % num_words)


    num_words = count_words(text3)
    print("Text 3")
    print("The word number is %d" % num_words)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What went wrong?

Comment: You can split the string using the split() function by space, and then getting the length of that array

Comment: please accept the answer is you feel like your problem has been solved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def count_words(text):

    num_words = 0
    num_words = len(text.split())
    return num_words
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```py
>>> import string
>>> def count_words(text):
...     for punc in string.punctuation:
...             text = text.replace(punc, "")
...     return len(text.split())
... 
>>> num_words = count_words(text1)
>>> print("Text 1")
Text 1
>>> print("The word number is %d" % num_words)
The word number is 22
>>>
```

we have replaced the punctuation marks with empty string in order to avoid them in counting in any sort of text where there are surrounded by spaces on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do so with few lines of code.

```
def count_words(text): #text is your argument, i.e., your sentence
print(text)
print("The word number is %d" %len(text.split()))
```

To use it:

```
text1 = 'There was no reason to believe that a young black boy at this time,in this place, could in any way alter history'
count_words('text1')
```